# Convert java.lang.String geometry to jts Geometry

Tags: jts

I have a geometry in java.lang.String format. I mean i take it directly from DB in as a java.lang.String which is stored in a variable. I want to convert it to jts Geometry type somehow. Is there any way to do it or what i'm trying to do is just a foolish approach?

Answer (score 10):

I assume that your geometry has the WKT ([Well Known Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)) format. If not, you can get it in the WKT format by using the `ST_AsText` method (requires spatial DB, which I assume you are using).

A simple example of how to get a geometry from a WKT String:

```
String wktString = "LINESTRING (0 0, 0 10)";
WKTReader reader = new WKTReader();
Geometry geom = reader.read(wktString);
```

Comment: Thank you. Which jar file do I need to import just to use WKTReader ? to work around this problem I'm calling a store procedure in PostgreSQL / PostGIS. I'm working in Grails 4 and Java 8. Thank you in advance for any response.

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.locationtech.jts/jts-core -->
``<dependency>
    <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
    <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.1</version>
</dependency>``

Answer (score 2):

You will have to first convert from String to Coordinates before you can convert it to a Geometry.

If the values are comma separated you could split them and create an array of Coordinates

```
String[] split=stringgeometry.split(",");
Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[split.length/2];
index = 0;  
for(int i=0;i<split.length;i+=2)
{
    coordinates[index]=new Coordinate(split[i], split[i+1]);
    index++;
}
```

After this you can create any Geometry that you want by using the GeometryFactory() class.
For example to create a line string,

```
Geometry geometry = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(coordinates);
```

Is this what you want to do?